# When I query my REST service with Breeze JS, the parameter is not passed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, breeze

I am working on a SPA with AngularJS and BreezeJS. The backend is implemented on ASP.NET Core MVC 6 and EF 6.1.3.

The REST service is running, but when I query the service with Breeze JS, the parameter is not passed.

E.g.

```
  [HttpGet]
  [EnableQuery]
  public IQueryable<Event> Events()
  {
  return this._contextProvider.Context.Events;
  }
```

I tried to call the service over the browser .../Context/Events?$filter=(Id%20eq%202). The result is still the same the filter is not apply.

What have I missed? How can I add OData to MVC6?

My Controller:

```
namespace FleetManagement.WebApi.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>Main REST / Breeze controller for the Fleet Management module.</summary>
    /// <seealso cref="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller"/>
    [BreezeController]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    [EnableQuery]
    [EnableBreezeQuery]
    public class ContextController : Controller
    {
        #region Fields.

        private readonly D4GEFContextProvider<FleetManagementContext> _contextProvider;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors / Desctructor.

        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ContextController"/> class.</summary>
        public ContextController()
        {
            var connectionString = "Data Source=lomoofsv14\\d4g;Initial Catalog=Test_Westfalen_D4G_Custom_RandomData;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=FMREST";
            this._contextProvider = new D4GEFContextProvider<FleetManagementContext>(connectionString);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods.

        /// <summary>Get a list of assets to a given asset filter and data profile.</summary>
        /// <param name="filters">The filters for the asset types is a string of type names e.g. 'Tractor, Trailer'.</param>
        /// <param name="profileUId">The profile identifier for the data filter.</param>
        /// <returns>IEnumerable&lt;Asset&gt;.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Asset> Assets(string filters, string profileUId)
        {
            return this._contextProvider.Context.GetAssets(filters, profileUId);
        }

        /// <summary>Assets the types.</summary>
        /// <returns>IQueryable&lt;System.String&gt;.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<string> AssetTypes()
        {
            return Enum.GetNames(typeof(AssetTypes))
                       .AsQueryable();
        }

        /// <summary>Data collection "Events".</summary>
        /// <returns>IQueryable&lt;Event&gt;.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Event> Events()
        {
            return this._contextProvider.Context.Events;
        }

        /// <summary>Metadata of the EF DBContext necessary for Breeze to build the JSON objects.</summary>
        /// <returns>System.String.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return this._contextProvider.Metadata();
        }

        /// <summary>Saves all changes to the database.</summary>
        /// <param name="saveBundle">The save bundle.</param>
        /// <returns>SaveResult.</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            this._contextProvider.BeforeSaveEntityDelegate = this.BeforeSaveEntityDelegate;
            this._contextProvider.AfterSaveEntitiesDelegate = this.AfterSaveEntitiesDelegate;

            return this._contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Tractor> Tractors()
        {
            return this._contextProvider.Context.Tractors;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Trailer> Trailers()
        {
            return this._contextProvider.Context.Trailers;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods.

        private void AfterSaveEntitiesDelegate(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap, List<KeyMapping> keyMappings)
        {
            // TractorToEvent Assign Event to tractor
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you actually capturing the parameter?  I don't see anything in the code you posted that would do this.

Comment: In my previous project ASP.NET 4.5 WEB API and BreezeJS, Breeze send the parameter as an OData Query.

My MVC6 controller is decorated with the attribute [BreezeController] like before. 

Sending a request over BreezeJS (SPA) to my ASP.NET 4.5 WEB API Controller provide the parameter in the EF query. (Watching with the SQL Profiler)

With the previous Version all is running fine, but with MVC 6 not.

Comment: Show us the code that illustrates the problem you just described.

Comment: This is my controller class:

Comment: I think I have to add some OData stuff.